# Bigquery Json output to CSV WKT Conversion Using python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gis, geopandas

**

```
emphasized text
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGIJ9.png)
**I have the following query in bigquery :

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(tract_geom) AS tract_geom ,
       geo_id,
       ST_AsGeoJSON(internal_point_geo) AS internal_point_geo,
       ST_INTERSECTS((tract_geom),(internal_point_geo)) AS INTERSECT_FLAG
FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_census_tracts.census_tracts_texas`
LIMIT 500
```

It can be exported as JSON File . I am aware that bigquery can export CSV but in this case , its not reliable due to the geographhy column and data type.

Hence , I am looking to convert JSON to CSV with WKT as data type for the all columns using python.

Has anyone dealt this scenario ?

are there any packages that can solve this?

Comment: Could you please expand what does not work reliably when you use BigQuery to export CSV, and how the output in that case differs from what you are trying to achieve? Also, if you need WKT, have you tried ST_AsText which returns WKT?

Comment: Hi Michael , I have tried using the ST_AsText and ST_AsGeoJSON in the sql query . When I export the results using the UI. It does return the CSV file. But from the row-5 onwards the results are off.

Comment: Where as when i export the results in JSON Format , it does return in a neat and structured way

Comment: Could you add details about what specifically you mean by "results are off"? An example could also help someone understand the issue.

Comment: Hi @MichaelEntin- I am unable to load the screenshot here . Is there anyway i can share the issue externally ?

Comment: Screenshots are not optimal. Description is better. Are you getting an error from BigQuery? Include the error text. Is the csv file not in expected format or corrupted? Include affected file content. Etc.

Comment: In Bigquery , there is no error . it returns out the csv file when extracted using console. When I open the file , from 5th row onwards , the cells go off position.

Comment: I would say the csv is corrupted.when exported.

Comment: Could you add that CSV file to the question? If it is corrupted after line 5, I suggest posting about 10 first lines, as they are exported, without any modifications.

Comment: I am unable to add the csv Michael . But I was able to add the screenshot. I hate to tell you this , but if you have bigquery , please run the above query .save it to a csv using the UI , and see how the results are . it would be much easier . the above query is using public datasets.

Comment: It looks like some strange formatting chosen by spreadsheet application. Raw text file willis be better. It would let someone see if this is export problem, or spreadsheet so problem.

Comment: Thank you . Anyways i overcame this issue by using bigquery client in python .This way m not exporting in any format. and using it for the next steps

Answer (score 0):

```
# Try this with a panda
with open('sample.json','r') as file_json:
   with open('new.csv','w')as file_w:
       for p in  file_json:
            file_w.write(p)
```